# Steps to execute threads in win32

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

I have two function , I need to run both of them parallel so i created thread for them in main function . the code is shown below:

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
......

     _beginthread(ModbusRead,0,(void*)12); 
     _beginthread(ModbusWrite,0,(void*)10);
}
```

The two functions are ModbusRead and ModbusWrite.

I have implemented only these two lines of thread in my code and they run these two function parallely apart from primary thread of main function.

let us say function ModbusRead is in thread1 and ModbusWrite is in thread2. I have to do following.

```
function ModbusWrite(thread2)
{
     if (condition1 true)
     {
         Pause thread1(donot run function ModbusRead)

         if(condition2 true)
               {
                   resume thread1(restart function ModbusRead)
               }
     }
}
```

Since I am new to thread i am wandering whether my thread implementation is correct or not and how can i fulfill the above mentioned condition.

Comment: It looks like you want mutual exclusion or events/signals of some kind. Inter-thread communication like this is a fairly complex issue, and probably not something which can be adequately explained in this context, as it requires careful design to avoid deadlocks and other issues. You could try referring to the MSDN documentation on synchronization: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686353(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Is this the same question as [your other one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20603507/what-is-the-correct-synchronization-method-for-the-thread-in-win32)?

Comment: yea a similar one .. just trying different way and i cannot paste the code so i created another question with more detail

Answer (score 0):

Thread1 must be a loop that checks an event each time through its loop. When the event is not set the thread will suspend at WaitForSingleObject.

```
while (WAIT_OBJECT_0 == WaitForSingleObject(hEvent, INFINITE))
{
   ...do some thread work
}
```

Other threads use CreateEvent initially, then SetEvent or ResetEvent to resume/pause thread1. The thread will not pause immediately: Only when its loop gets back to WaitForSingleObject.

In practice you probably also need a way to signal the thread when it should exit. This can be done by using WaitForMultipleObjects, with one event for resume/pause and a second event for exit.