# What is the correct synchronization method for the thread in win32

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

I have created following things for thread

```
int Data_Of_Thread_1 = 1;
int Data_Of_Thread_2 = 2;
Handle_Of_Thread_1 = 0;
Handle_Of_Thread_2 = 0;
HANDLE Array_Of_Thread_Handles[2];

Handle_Of_Thread_1 = CreateThread( NULL, 0,ModbusRead, &Data_Of_Thread_1, 0, NULL);  

Handle_Of_Thread_2 = CreateThread( NULL, 0,ModbusWrite, &Data_Of_Thread_2, 0, NULL);
```

Now i have to control the execution of these two threads. The condition is as follows:

```
function ModbusWrite
{
 if (condition1 true)
   {
     Pause thread1

     if(condition2 true)
           {
               resume thread1
           }
     }
 }
```

I have gone through the sites. they say synchronisation element as event, mutex, semaphore. etc. I think i have to use either event or mutex. But i am not quite clear about how to use them both. First we create either create event or create mutex then how to apply those event or mutex in my above condition. Also i am not clear about "WaitForSingleObject" function. where and how to implement . If anyone can help me with the code then it would be grateful.

Comment: What protects the conditions? What changes them? Also, *never* think in terms of compelling a thread to do the right thing from the outside by pausing or resuming it. Just code it to do the right thing *itself* in the first place. Don't think "how do I control thread1 so it does the right thing", think "how do I write the code for thread1 itself so it does the right thing".

Comment: The conditions are the external one. i am interfacing my program with external software when they trigger something, I have to run these two functions. Also I have to continuously check whether the external software has triggered or not. I have interfaced with two external party . So I have created two thread so that it can check continuously whether they have triggered.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, one typically uses [event objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682655%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to wait for conditions without wasting CPU.  If the external software you're interfacing with provides some sort of asynchronous callback mechanism, then you'd want to do something like this:

```
// Create an anonymous auto-reset event, initial state unsignaled
HANDLE hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, NULL);
...

void ThreadProcedure()
{
    while (threadShouldContinueRunning())
    {
        // Wait until event is signaled
        WaitForSingleObject(hEvent, INFINITE);

        // Now the thread has woken up, check the condition and respond
        // accordingly
    }
}
...

void OnExternalCallback()
{
    // Called from external library when the condition becomes true -- signal
    // the worker thread to resume
    SetEvent(hEvent);
}
...

// Don't forget to cleanup
CloseHandle(hEvent);
```

Now, if the external library does *not* provide any sort of callback mechanism to inform you when the condition becomes true, you're in trouble.  In that case, the only way to detect when the condition becomes true is to continuously poll it, optionally sleeping in between to avoid burning CPU time.  The major downside of this, of course, is that you introduce unnecessary latency in detecting the condition change (the latency amount is the sleep time), or you waste a lot of CPU (and therefore power/battery life) spinning.

```
void ThreadProcedure()
{
    while (threadShouldContinueRunning())
    {
        // Avoid polling if at all possible -- this adds latency and/or wastes
        // CPU and power/battery life
        if (externalConditionIsTrue())
        {
            // Handle
        }
        else
        {
            Sleep(50);  // Tune this number to balance latency vs. CPU load
        }
    }
}
```